# Parse .bin file in JS to array of floats

Tags: javascript, binary

I have sph.bin file, containing something like

```
����j.  4   4�3j]��*$����i.8��0�0f_+��#N���h.ߥ0�/�_��d#���h.�0m/�_��d#����h.�0k/�_��d#l���h.�0k/�_��d# ���h.0k/�_��d#����h.�0k/�_��d#���h.0k/�_��d#|���h.0k/�_��d#����h.�0k/�_��d#N���h.�0k/�_��d#����h.�0k/�_��d# ���h.0k/�_��d#���h.�0k/
```

which is set 16bits long floats (halffloat). How do I read them in JS?

Comment: Forgot my vote instantly closes now,  but anyway some more info here should help -> https://github.com/petamoriken/float16

Comment: This might also help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678432/decompressing-half-precision-floats-in-javascript